# Cannot change headings to random colour on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

When the page loads a random colour is generated and applied to the 'TEST COLOUR' text and the headings of the RSS feed.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/nqkH4/

The trouble is the RSS feed heading's colour does not change.

I setup an event, click 'TEST COLOUR' and the heading colour will change so I've figured it is to do with dynamically added elements.

I have looked at .on() but have not managed to get it to work.

Could someone post the code needed to change the headings colour on page load?

tia

jQuery plugin is FeedEk:
http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html

CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#divRss').FeedEk({
      FeedUrl : 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss'
    });

    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);

    $('#example, .itemTitle a').css("color", getHex(r,g,b));

    $('#example').click(function() {

        $('.itemTitle a').css("color", getHex(r,g,b));

    });

    function intToHex(n){
        n = n.toString(16);
        if( n.length < 2) 
            n = "0"+n; 
        return n;
    }

    function getHex(r, g, b){
        return '#'+intToHex(r)+intToHex(g)+intToHex(b); 
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="example">TEST COLOUR</div>
<div id="divRss"></div>
```

CSS

```
.feedEkList{width:450px; list-style:none outside none;background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #D3CAD7; padding:4px 6px; color:#3E3E3E;}
.feedEkList li{border-bottom:1px solid #D3CAD7; padding:5px;}
.feedEkList li:last-child{border-bottom:none;}
.itemTitle a{font-weight:bold; color:#4EBAFF; text-decoration:none }
.itemTitle a:hover{ text-decoration:underline }
.itemDate{font-size:11px;color:#AAAAAA;}

#example { font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: You would need to run the code after the ajax request performed by feedEk is finished, however feedEk doesn't appropriately provide a way of doing that.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. All my attempts at callbacks failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-Edit-**

In response to comments below, the `timeout` is unreliable. I've extended the included library to allow for a callback function. Default is `alert('done')`, but it can be passed in as an argument to do whatever you'd like.

> Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nqkH4/8/

Alternatively, as discussed below, you could poll the contents of your target div to see if its content has changes, when it has, you know the call has completed.

<strike>I think the issue is there is a *slight* delay with content hitting the DOM and the script trying to style it. It've gotten it to work with a small `timeout`.</strike>

```
 setTimeout(function () {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var color = getHex(r, g, b);

    $('#example, .itemTitle a').css("color", color);

}, 50);
```

> Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqkH4/6/

Comment: The delay is coming from the ajax request. A setTimeout may solve it, but for it to work for everyone the delay would have to be significant to account for cellular networks, resulting in a significant delay before the content displays even if the request happened in 50ms.

Comment: I suppose you could set an interval to check the `html()` of the `div` in question to see if it has been populated? Then fire a makeshift callback? I tried to pass a callback function to `FeedEk()` to no avail.

Comment: Yes, a setInterval would be more appropriate than a setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks, I used setInterval to check every 50ms as sometimes that wasn't enough time.